# Differences in services provided by grid computing and cloud computing

Tags: distributed-systems

What are differences in services provided by grid computing and cloud computing?

From http://ccskguide.org/cloud-computing-vs-grid-computing/ and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-cloudgrid/

> While grid computing facilitates access to computing resources as if they were **public utilities**, cloud computing offers **on-demand resource provisioning**.

The article says grid computing provide computing resources just like public utilities (such as electricity). Are public utilities different from on-demand resources provisioning?

It also says one component of cloud computing is utility computing, just like paying for a public utility such as electricity:

> Cloud computing is a development on grid computing. It requires three
>   fundamental components:
>
> - Thin clients (alternatively, clients with a thin-thick switch may be used)
> - Grid computing
> - Utility computing (i.e. paying for resources used from shared servers, similar to paying for a public utility, such as electricity)

So do both grid computing and cloud computing provide their services just like electricity?

Thanks!

Comment: This does not strike me as a CS question; what is the *scientific* problem/question here?